# Computed variable is undefined after button click

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, vue.js

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_vue_simple_audio_2

In Main.vue

I tried to assign new value to `this.player.currentTrack`, by following this [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

```
selectTrack: function selectTrack(id) {
  this.player.currentTrack = Object.assign(
    {},
    this.player.currentTrack,
    { currentTrack: id },
  );
  this.player.elapsed = Object.assign(
    {},
    this.player.elapsed,
    { elapsed: 0 },
  );
  // this.play();
},
```

It seems no error, until I click the button

[image: Error]

```
Error: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined
```

In Main.vue, `currentTrack.duration`

```
<div class="player__timer">
  <div class="player__timer__elapsed" v-text="player.elapsed"></div>
  
  <div class="player__timer__total" v-text="currentTrack.duration"></div>
</div>

<div class="slider player__progress-bar">  
  <input type="range" :value="player.elapsed" :max="currentTrack.duration" />
</div>
```

From the image, you can see that there is a value: `274`, which is the value of `currentTrack.duration` **initially**. After I click the button, `currentTrack` becomes undefined. `currentTrack` is a `computed` value.

Answer (score 0):

You used `currentTrack.duration` instead of `player.currentTrack.duration`, try this:

```
<div class="player__timer">
  <div class="player__timer__elapsed" v-text="player.elapsed"></div>

  <div class="player__timer__total" v-text="player.currentTrack.duration"></div>
</div>

<div class="slider player__progress-bar">  
  <input type="range" :value="player.elapsed" :max="player.currentTrack.duration" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, For currentTrack there are actually 2 of them (with the same name). One is player.currentTrack and the other one is computed: { currentTrack: function ().... }. I need the one in computed. How do I use computed in template?

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way to do object.assign. My method above is wrong.

```
let player = {
  currentTrack: 0,
  other: ""
};

console.log(player);

player = Object.assign(
  {},
  player,
  { currentTrack: 2}
);

console.log(player);
```